# keras tensorflow2 get results for the training data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, predict

In keras we could train model using `fit` command and then use `predict`.

```
Dcnn=model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
model.predict(test_dataset,verbose=True)
```

when we use `fit` method we get accuracy results as below. Lets say after 5 epochs we got accuracy of 98.62% on the training data. Now if we use `model.predict(x_train,verbose=True)` would we get the exact same accuracy and exactly same predictions for each observation as shown in the outcome of fit method? if not, why?

```
Epoch 5/5
61/61 - 11s - loss: 0.0320 - tp: 1602.0000 - fp: 18.0000 - tn: 321.0000 - fn: 9.0000 - accuracy: 0.9862
```

## update1

I updated commands as below
`Dcnn.fit(train_dataset,
         epochs=NB_EPOCHS,
         verbose=2,validation_data=test_dataset)`

and i got below results

```
Epoch 5/5

61/61 - 11s - loss: 0.0320 - tp: 1602.0000 - fp: 18.0000 - tn: 321.0000 - fn: 9.0000 - accuracy: 0.9862 - precision: 0.9889 - recall: 0.9944 - auc: 0.9990 - val_loss: 0.9760 - val_tp: 161.0000 - val_fp: 22.0000 - val_tn: 9.0000 - val_fn: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.8854 - val_precision: 0.8798 - val_recall: 1.0000 - val_auc: 0.7169
```

Now if i try `model.predict(test_dataset,verbose=True)` I get 88.54% accuracy - same as output of the fit method.

If i run `model.predict(train_dataset,verbose=True)`, would i get accuracy 98.62%? if no, then why?

Comment: would you accept the answer? or would you want more explanation?

Comment: sorry for the delay...if you could add a link to official documentation that supports your answer it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `fit()` the model is still training and the results are not accurate. Calling `predict()` is accurate since the model is done training.

You can't see the probabilities for the classes using `fit`. That is due to the weights being changed after each batch based on the probabilities. Meaning that from a batch to another you have different weights, and as such would give different answers even on the same data.

In order to get the real probabilities, you can use `predict()`. Predict and fit wouldn't return the same probabilities since `predict` returns for the whole set while `fit` is an average over all of the batches (with varying weights between batches).

Also, you might be confused, calling `model.fit()` returns a History object that contains the values for the loss and accuracy and such. Calling `Dcnn.predict()` would give an error since History objects don't have a "predict" attribute. `model.predict()` should be used to get the predictions which in turn can be used to calculate probabilities.

The weights of a model are saved in the instance itself, such that after calling `fit()` the weights are changed and saved automatically by the model.

Comment: My answer still stands, predict and fit are different. `fit()` changes the model after each batch and the accuracy is an average over all batches. `predict()` gives the exact result since the model isn't changing anymore.`

Comment: i got `accuracy: 0.9862` after 5th epoch. Are you saying that that accuracy is average  of all batches? but if i run `model.predict(test_dataset,verbose=True)` and update `fit` to `Dcnn.fit(train_dataset,
         epochs=NB_EPOCHS,
         verbose=2,validation_data=test_dataset)`, I get exact same results as the output of fit.

Comment: You are confused about your question, there are diferences between how the test data and train data are treated in`fit()`. The models weights get updated by the results of each batch of the training set and the final result you see is an average of those. **The result of `fit` on train data is an averge of results for each batch on a changing model**.    Test set is used only at the end of every epoch,  after all the weights have changed, so the result of fit test data and predict test data would be the same.

Comment: so, if i want to see what would be the accuracy for the train data, i should run `model.predict(x_train,verbose=True)`? even though the results won't match with output of `fit()`, that is the correct accuracy that I could expect to get?

Comment: yes! but also, the training accuracy shouldn't matter, it's the generalization accuracy that matters, that is the validation or test set accuracy.